# Synchronize time with NTP on very variable latency

Tags: ruby, time, synchronization, ntp

I want to synchronize time using NTP as accurately as possible, but I have a big problem: the network latency with the timeserver is extremely variable (ranging from 80ms to 900ms).

What would be best way to account for latency?

```
sock = UDPSocket.new
sock.connect("pool.ntp.org", "ntp")

timeStart = Time.new.to_f

sock.print ntp_msg
sock.flush
#maybe I should put here timeStart?
sock.recvfrom

timeEnd = Time.new.to_f

latency=timeEnd-timeStart
timeDifference = ntp_recv_time-timeStart
realDifference = timeDifference-latency # maybe should divide latency or what?
```

that's partial ruby code I'm using now, theoretically `realDifference` should always be equal but due latency it's different every time...

also if I do several tests and take average would it be more precise?
any suggestions, recommendations welcomed :)

Comment: NTP client/server implementations already handle this, by repeatedly synchronizing and averaging the latencies and accounting for other delays in processing time.  You could try to reproduce that behavior, but you're almost certainly better off just running an NTP client on the machine and then trusting the hardware clock on that machine to be as good as possible.  You're certainly not going to get a more accurate time by implementing your own solution.  If you really need to do this for some reason, check out the NTP client source code to see what it does.

Comment: I need it for Ruby and those few libs I found doesn't take latency in account at all. But thanks anyway, I'll look at other NTP client implementations for C etc.